# HTML attribute image/* is valid?

Tags: html, image, mime-types, content-type, favicon

adding `image/*` will make browser to interpret themselves and will it valid?

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/*" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/588px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png?20230305195327"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/*" href="https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/image8-2.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

It is [valid](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#http-token-code-point), but pointless.

There aren't any browsers which support favicons but don't support at least one data format for it which is an image MIME type.

Compared with omitting the optional type attribute entirely then *at best* it will make no difference and *at worst* a browser will not recognise `image/*` and won't load an image format that it does support.